# экспорт объекта с возможностью использовать в его методах его же методы

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this

есть у меня такой объект с санками, сделал так для удобства экспорта, но наткнулся на проблему, мне нужно при удачном выполнении санки updateStatus, которую я запускаю в компоненте, запустить другую, getStatus, но не могу реализовать, ошибка this undefined

```
export const Thunks = {
  getStatus: (userId) => (dispatch) => {
    profileAPI.getProfileStatus(userId)
      .then(data => {
        dispatch(setUserStatus(data));
      });
  },
  updateStatus: (status) => (dispatch, useState) => {
    let id = useState().auth.id
    profileAPI.updateProfileStatus(status)
      .then(response => {
        if ( response.resultCode === 0 ) {
          dispatch(this.getStatus(id)); //вопрос к этой строчке
        }
      });
  }
}
```

Вопроса два:

1. Как реализовать, если это возможно?
2. Как правильно экспортировать одним объектом или по отдельности

UPD:
постарался переписать, как предложили в ответах, но всё равно не получилось

```js
export const Thunks = {
  getProfile: function (userId) {
    return (dispatch) => {
      profileAPI.getProfile(userId)
        .then(data => {
          const checkedData = objIterationWithReplacement(data, null, '');
          dispatch(setUserProfile({ ...checkedData, photoUrl: Volodymyr }));
        });
    };
  },

  updateProfileInfo: function (values) {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
      const userId = getState().auth.id;
      profileAPI.updateProfileInfo(values)
        .then(response => {
          if ( response.resultCode === 0 ) {
            dispatch(this.getProfile(userId));
          }
        });
    };
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае можно использовать имя переменной `Thunks`

```
dispatch(Thunks.getStatus(id)); //вопрос к этой строчке
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, я так и делал. Просто хотел узнать возможно ли это через this, для большего понимания. Или нужно переписать по-другому сам объект. Думал может что-то через класс придумать. И вообще, как правильнее при экспорте поступать?

Comment: @Volodymyr, можно и через `this`, если поменять стрелочную функцию `updateStatus` на обычную: `updateStatus: function(status) { return (dispatch, useState) => { ...  }}`

Comment: Попытался, но всё равно не получилось. Мне кажется, что проблема из-за потери контекста вызова самого метода. Нужно как-то связать с использованием call & apply?

Comment: @Volodymyr, в комментарии выше пример, который работает, если он у тебя не сработал, значит ты сделал что-то другое